# Use the Google Maps API to search within a predefined set of data

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

My client has a list of store locations. Now what he wants is to let users search for any of these locations, based on the address the user submitted. The search results will be based on the proximity of the locations.

So basically what I am looking for is Google Maps functionality, but based **only** on the set of (geographical) data I provide.

Do any of you know if this is even possible, and if so, what can be a good starting point to learn more about it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found the answer to my own question at these links: 
- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html
- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlgeocode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is possible. I guess you have in you database set of the latitude and longitude entries for each store. You can get users current location with geocoder and measure distance with `distanceFrom` call to find the nearest store.

Comment: This is very close to the solution I eventualy came up with. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're welcome to copy the code directly from [here](http://www.calvert.ch/geodesix/offices.htm), it does exactly what you request.

You'll need offices.htm, offices.js and logo.png.

To prepare your list of offices, you might find [this Excel addin](http://www.calvert.ch/geodesix) useful